# uninitialized constant in class_eval

Tags: ruby

I have a method call that does a class_eval:

```
class BatchRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one_document :contact
end
```

This works fine:

```
def has_one_document(association_name, options={})
  class_eval <<-EOS
      def #{ association_name }
        MongoidContainer::Contact.where(#{ name.underscore }_id: id).first
      end
  EOS
end
```

But this below gives me "uninitialized constant BatchRecord::Contact":

```
def has_one_document(association_name, options={})
  class_eval <<-EOS
      def #{ association_name }
        MongoidContainer.const_get(#{association_name.to_s.classify}).where(#{ name.underscore }_id: id).first
      end
  EOS
end
```

I cannot understand why it is producing BatchRecord::Contact when it should be producing MongoidContainer::Contact. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ruby doesn't have a method `where`.  You need at least one more tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed code:

```
def has_one_document(association_name, options={})
  class_eval <<-EOS
    def #{ association_name }
      MongoidContainer.const_get(#{association_name.to_s.classify.inspect})
        .where(#{ name.underscore }_id: id).first
    end
  EOS
end
```

Note the added `.inspect` on line 4.

[`classify` returns a string](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-classify), so your middle line would expand to

```
MongoidContainer.const_get(Contact).where # ...
```

This tries to search for a constant named `Contact` in the current scope (your `BatchRecord` class), which fails. `const_get` takes a string, so you have to `inspect` your string before putting it in an `eval` (or `class_eval`).

Comment: Good answer. A small point: [Module#const_get](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html#method-i-const_get) can take a symbol or a string (in v2.1 anyway). You've been AWOL.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks, didn't know that. Edited.